# gRPC asynchronous rpc throws seg fault

Tags: c++, grpc

Updates: I found out if I call contactRemoteDone() inside of the contactRemote(), it does process. But if I call it outside of contactRemote(),but right after it, it throws a seg fault.So

```
for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
c1->contactRemote(x,request,response[x]);
c1->contactRemoteDone(x,response[x]);
}
```

doesn't work.

I tried to write a small program to test my implementation of gRPC asynchronous service. It throws a seg fault when I tried to access the response and when I used GDB to debug, I could not understand what the backtrace actually means and I did not find anything doing a Google search. The following is my code.

```
grpc_async_client.h
#include "sundial_grpc.grpc.pb.h"
#include "sundial_grpc.pb.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::CompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using sundial_rpc::SundialRequest;
using sundial_rpc::SundialResponse;
using sundial_rpc::Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC;
 
#ifndef SAC
#define SAC
class TxnManager;
class Sundial_Async_Client{
public:
    Sundial_Async_Client(std::string* channel);
    Status contactRemote(uint64_t node_id,SundialRequest& request, SundialResponse* response);
    Status contactRemoteDone(uint64_t node_id, SundialResponse* response);
private:
    //std::unique_ptr<Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC::Stub> stub_[8];
    std::unique_ptr<Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC::Stub> stub_;
    CompletionQueue cq;
};

#endif
```

```
grpc_async_client.cpp
#include "sundial_grpc.grpc.pb.h"
#include "sundial_grpc.pb.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "grpc_async_client.h"

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::CompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using sundial_rpc::SundialRequest;
using sundial_rpc::SundialResponse;
using sundial_rpc::Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC;

Sundial_Async_Client::Sundial_Async_Client(std::string* channel){
  for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
        if(i==1)
            continue;
     std::string server_address = channel[i];
     printf("async client is connecting to server %s\n",server_address.c_str());       
  
    stub_=Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC::NewStub(grpc::CreateChannel(
                server_address, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
    }
};

//toDo: more than 2 nodes
Status Sundial_Async_Client:: contactRemote(uint64_t node_id,SundialRequest& request, SundialResponse* response){
    ClientContext context;
    Status status;
    std::unique_ptr<ClientAsyncResponseReader<SundialResponse>> rpc(stub_->PrepareAsynccontactRemote(&context,request,&cq));
    rpc->StartCall();

    rpc->Finish(response, &status, (void*)1);
    printf("sends a request %d \n",node_id);
    return status;
}

Status Sundial_Async_Client::contactRemoteDone(uint64_t node_id, SundialResponse* response){
    void* got_tag;
    bool ok = false;
    // Block until the next result is available in the completion queue "cq".
    // The return value of Next should always be checked. This return value
    // tells us whether there is any kind of event or the cq_ is shutting down.
    GPR_ASSERT(cq.Next(&got_tag, &ok));

    // Verify that the result from "cq" corresponds, by its tag, our previous
    // request.
    GPR_ASSERT(got_tag == (void*)1);
    // ... and that the request was completed successfully. Note that "ok"
    // corresponds solely to the request for updates introduced by Finish().
    GPR_ASSERT(ok);
    printf("node %d is done\n",node_id);
    return Status::OK;
   
}
```

```
grpc_async_server.h
#include "sundial_grpc.grpc.pb.h"
#include "sundial_grpc.pb.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::ServerCompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using sundial_rpc::SundialRequest;
using sundial_rpc::SundialResponse;
using sundial_rpc::Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC;

#ifndef SAS
#define SAS

class SundialAsyncServiceImp {
    public:
    ~SundialAsyncServiceImp();
    void run();
    std::mutex mtx;
    private:
    // Class encompasing the state and logic needed to serve a request.
  class CallData {
   public:
    // Take in the "service" instance (in this case representing an asynchronous
    // server) and the completion queue "cq" used for asynchronous communication
    // with the gRPC runtime.
    CallData(Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* cq);

    void Proceed();

   private:
    // The means of communication with the gRPC runtime for an asynchronous
    // server.
    Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC::AsyncService* service_;
    // The producer-consumer queue where for asynchronous server notifications.
    ServerCompletionQueue* cq_;
    // Context for the rpc, allowing to tweak aspects of it such as the use
    // of compression, authentication, as well as to send metadata back to the
    // client.
    ServerContext ctx_;

    // What we get from the client.
    SundialRequest request_;
    // What we send back to the client.
    SundialResponse response_;

    // The means to get back to the client.
    ServerAsyncResponseWriter<SundialResponse> responder_;

    // Let's implement a tiny state machine with the following states.
    enum CallStatus { CREATE, PROCESS, FINISH };
    CallStatus status_;  // The current serving state.
  };
    void HandleRpcs();
    std::unique_ptr<ServerCompletionQueue> cq_;
    Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC::AsyncService service_;
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server_;

    
};

#endif
```

```
grpc_aynsc_server.cpp
#include "sundial_grpc.grpc.pb.h"
#include "sundial_grpc.pb.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "grpc_async_server.h"
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpcpp/health_check_service_interface.h>
#include <grpcpp/ext/proto_server_reflection_plugin.h>

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::ServerCompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using sundial_rpc::SundialRequest;
using sundial_rpc::SundialResponse;
using sundial_rpc::Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC;

SundialAsyncServiceImp::~SundialAsyncServiceImp(){
    server_->Shutdown();
    // Always shutdown the completion queue after the server.
    cq_->Shutdown();
}

void SundialAsyncServiceImp::run(){
 
    uint32_t num_nodes = 0;
    
    std::string port("0.0.0.0:50051");
    
    ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(port, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service_);
    cq_ = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
    server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << port << std::endl<<"\n";
    HandleRpcs();
}

SundialAsyncServiceImp::CallData::CallData(Sundial_GRPC_ASYNC::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* cq): 
service_(service), cq_(cq), responder_(&ctx_), status_(CREATE) {
      Proceed();
    }
int processRequest(SundialRequest* request, SundialResponse* response){
 if (request->request_type() == SundialRequest::SYS_REQ) {
        response->set_response_type( SundialResponse::SYS_RESP );
        return 1;
    }
    int a =0;
    //some processing
    while(a<100000){
        a++;
    }
    return 1;
}

void SundialAsyncServiceImp::CallData::Proceed(){
    
    if (status_ == CREATE) {
        status_ = PROCESS;
        service_->RequestcontactRemote(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                                  this);
      } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
        new CallData(service_, cq_);
        int a = processRequest(&request_ , &response_);
        status_ = FINISH;
        responder_.Finish(response_, Status::OK, this);
      } else {
        GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
        delete this;
      }
}



void SundialAsyncServiceImp::HandleRpcs(){
    new CallData(&service_, cq_.get());
    void* tag;  
    bool ok;
    mtx.unlock();
    while (true) {
      GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
      GPR_ASSERT(ok);
      static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
    }
}
```

```
main.cpp
#include "grpc_async_server.h"
#include "grpc_async_client.h"
Sundial_Async_Client* c1;
SundialAsyncServiceImp* s1 ;
void * start_sync_rpc_server(void* input){
    s1->run();
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
std::string channel_async[2];
channel_async[0]=server_address;

s1 = new SundialAsyncServiceImp();
pthread_t * pthread_rpc1 = new pthread_t;
s1->mtx.lock();
pthread_create(pthread_rpc1, NULL, start_sync_rpc_server,NULL);
s1->mtx.lock();
c1=new Sundial_Async_Client(channel_async);
SundialRequest request;
SundialResponse* response[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    SundialResponse r;
    response[i]=&r;
}
for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
c1->contactRemote(x,request,response[x]);
}
printf("sends all requests out\n");
int y=0;
while(y<10){
    c1->contactRemoteDone(y,response[y]);

}
}
```

It runs smoothly until it reaches the while loop in main. It throws a seg fault. If I use GDB, I get the following:

```
Thread 1 "rundb" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
grpc::internal::InterceptorBatchMethodsImpl::RunInterceptors (
    this=this@entry=0x7ffff6a9ec58)
    at /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/interceptor_common.h:264
264     RunServerInterceptors();
(gdb) backtrace
#0  grpc::internal::InterceptorBatchMethodsImpl::RunInterceptors (
    this=this@entry=0x7ffff6a9ec58)
    at /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/interceptor_common.h:264
#1  0x000000000041c8aa in grpc::internal::CallOpSet<grpc::internal::CallOpSendInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpSendMessage, grpc::internal::CallOpClientSendClose, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvMessage<sundial_rpc::SundialResponse>, grpc::internal::CallOpClientRecvStatus>::RunInterceptorsPostRecv (this=0x7ffff6a9eb18)
    at /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/call_op_set.h:826
#2  grpc::internal::CallOpSet<grpc::internal::CallOpSendInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpSendMessage, grpc::internal::CallOpClientSendClose, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvInitialMetadata, grpc::internal::CallOpRecvMessage<sundial_rpc::SundialResponse>, grpc::internal::CallOpClientRecvStatus>::FinalizeResult (
    this=0x7ffff6a9eb18, tag=0x7fffffffdd18, status=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/call_op_set.h:920
#3  0x00007ffff7c95f23 in grpc_impl::CompletionQueue::AsyncNextInternal(void**, bool*, gpr_timespec) () from /usr/local/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
#4  0x000000000040ab9c in grpc_impl::CompletionQueue::Next (ok=0x7fffffffdd17, 
    tag=0x7fffffffdd18, this=0x7ffff6a42078)
    at /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue_impl.h:179
#5  Sundial_Async_Client::contactRemoteDone (this=0x7ffff6a42070, 
    node_id=node_id@entry=0, response=response@entry=0x7fffffffdd70)
    at grpc/grpc_async_client.cpp:93
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--ret
#6  0x000000000040a6ac in main () at grpc/main.cpp:38
```

main.cpp:38 is `c1->contactRemoteDone(y,response[y]);` and grpc_async_client.cpp:93 is `GPR_ASSERT(cq.Next(&got_tag, &ok));`. I'm really lost on this error message and really wish someone could help me out.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please don't do something like `pthread_t * pthread_rpc1 = new pthread_t;`. Define `pthread_rpc1` as a *non* pointer variable (i.e. `pthread_t pthread_rpc1;`) and use the address-of operator `&` (as in `&pthread_rpc1`) when you need a pointer to it. In fact, you seem to be using pointers and `new` maybe a little more than needed elsewhere as well. Are you coming from a language where `new` is mandatory to create objects? It's not needed in C++.

Comment: I also recommend that you learn about [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: Thank you about that. I have most of my background in C and Java so I don't always get used to objects in c++. Thanks for the hints

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    SundialResponse r;
    response[i]=&r;
}
```

Each `SundialResponse` is being destructed per iteration. Do this instead:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    SundialResponse* r = new SundialResponse();
    response[i]=r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try the fix but the same issue keeps happening. Now it either gets stuck the first iteration of the while loop or throws the same seg fault. I found this issue extremely strange. Thanks in advance